# Canonical way to map a function to diagonal elements of a square matrix?

Tags: matrix, programming

What is the Canonical way to map a function to only the diagonal elements of a matrix?

For example, given

```
 A = {{E, 0}, {0, E}}
```

I wanted to take the log of the diagonal elements only to obtain  `{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}`

I came up with these

```
 MapAt[Log[#] &, A, Table[{i, i}, {i, Length[A]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  result = Log[Diagonal[A]];
  ReplacePart[A, {i_, i_} :> result[[i]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since in Mathematica the rule of thumb is that there should be at least 10 different ways to do the same thing, I think there is room to find a better approach.

Comment: Maybe using `MapIndexed` rather than `MapAt` ?

Comment: Also possible : `ReplacePart[A, {i_, i_} :> Log[A[[i, i]]]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using  b.gates.you.know.what's idea:

```
With[{f = Log}, 
     MapIndexed[Function[{x, id}, If[Equal @@ id, f[x], x]], A, {2}]]
```

---

Using an *undocumented* function:

```
res = A;
With[{f = Log}, LinearAlgebra`Private`SetMatrixDiagonal[res, f[Diagonal[res]]]];
res
```

Note that this function modifies matrices given to it, so you'll need to make a copy if you still need the starting matrix.

Answer (score 3):

A modification of a method given by [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) in [Mathematica programming:  an advanced introduction](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/Book.html)

```
A// MapThread[ReplacePart, {#, Log@Diagonal[#], Range[Length@#]}]&
```

> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}

There is a discussion in this old SO question: [Changing the Diagonals of a Matrix with Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154924/changing-the-diagonals-of-a-matrix-with-mathematica)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there are 10 different ways, but here's a third.

Start with A and subtract off the diagonal, modify the diagonal with your function (Log) and add it back in:

```
A - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[A]] + DiagonalMatrix[Log[Diagonal[A]]]
```